# Suggestions for creating an app or a web part in a Team Site

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx-webparts, sharepoint-hosted-app, team-sites, microsoft-teams

I would like to develop a user control with a text box where the user will enter his/her UserID and click the button to see some info which is populated by my own REST API.

Is there a web part out of box which I can leverage to do this kind of functionality?

I have a SharePoint site collection created by Teams. I'm the site collection admin of this team site. I would like to deploy in this site.

Answer (score 1):

```
 <input type="text" name="userID" id="userID"><input type="button" onclick="getUser()" value="submit">
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function getUser() {
        let id = $("#userID").val();
        if(id!=""){
            $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/getuserbyid(" + id + ")",
            headers: {
                "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
                "content-type": "application/json;odata=verbose",
            },
            success: function (data) {
                console.log(data.d)
            },
            error: function (xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                alert("No user");
            }
        });
        }else{
            alert("please enter user id")
        }
        
    }
</script>
```

You could get user info in `data.d`,you could show the user info which you wanted to page.
Test result:
[image]